# The new value for the (if) condition has no effect

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a JS code block just like below. the code will redirect user to login page after 30 sec but if the user clicks anywhere on the page the process will be reset. theoretically  the code logic is true `setInterval` and `EventListener` both works fine but when I click somewhere in the page although  global variable (counter) changes to 0 but (if) condition in the `setInterval` has no effects and still (counter)  variable remain unchanged and the redirection will be happened!!!

```js
var counter = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  if (counter >= 30) {
    // commented below line for testing with run code in stack overflow. 
    // In real code it will be uncommented.
    // document.location = 'http://localhost/login'; 
    console.log('redirect');
  } else {
    counter++;
  }
}, 1000);

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  counter = 0;
}, true);
```

Comment: Is your actual code **exactly** like what you posted?

Comment: I ran this code, and the if statement does have an effect. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: user click must make 30 sec delay for redirection

Comment: @M.J.Ahmadi that's what this code does (maybe not exactly 30 seconds). Once the counter reaches 30 the user will be redirected.

Comment: @M.J.Ahmadi well the code you posted works, so I don't know how anybody can help you.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are trying to achieve here, if ater 30 seconds the user has not click the document it will be directed to the desired location, but if the user click on the document the 30second counter resets, if that is the case you got that working ... Unless we are missing something else ...

Comment: @RicardoSanchez, I know the code must works but it is not working in my Firefox & Chrome even after I use `clearInterval` as @mplungjan sagested :(

Comment: @Karan. I declared counter variable globally as you can see in the code above

Comment: Maybe you have another global counter variable in your code that is causing the problem?

Comment: @RicardoSanchez. even if I have another variable with same name when I use `var counter = 0;` this will overwrite everything

Comment: True but still not an ideal situation if that is the case, you mention that the code doesn't work on Chrome or Firefox, there is nothing special on the code that those browsers can't handle, have you try using node.js on the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work

Here is a perhaps more understandable version using clearInterval

```js
let secs = 5;
let tId;

function int() {
  clearInterval(tId);
  counter = secs;
  tId = setInterval(function() {
    if (counter <= 0) {
      document.location = 'https://github.com';
    } else {
      counter--;
    }
    document.getElementById("x").innerText = counter
  }, 1000);
}
document.addEventListener('click', int);
int()
```

```html
<span id="x"></span>
```

Comment: I checked my code and found `header('Refresh:30;url=...)` somewhere in my code that cased the problem. I accept your answer for using `clearInterval` thanks.